# Inserting multiple rows into a database where each row references another row in c# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, parent-child

I am attempting to store a tree structure in a database. For the sake of example I am using a single table, where each row can reference another row.

```
Id | Name | Parent
------------------
 1 | t1   | NULL
 2 | t2   | 1
 3 | t3   | 1
 4 | t4   | 2
 5 | t5   | 3
```

The way i currently populate the table is by submitting each row individually and then i query again to get the parent ID. I figure there must be a better way of doing this, with fewer queries and all.

Any help would be great .

Thanks

Comment: Are you using LINQ To SQL or LINQ to Entites

Answer (score 0):

Consider passing a table valued parameter into a stored procedure and let the procedure do the chatty stuff. LINQ to SQL may not be able to handle this but the code to do this using plain old ADO.Net is not too bad.

[Here is the documentation on table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and

[Here is a tutorial on how to use them](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/)

Comment: Using a stored procedure wont help really. The issue is that a row needs to reference another row before i have submitted the reference row.

Comment: Once you get into that sproc with a list of records you have all sorts of options in addition to reducing the query calls. You can temporarily turn off Identity and batch insert with NULL for parent. You can do a batch update after the insert. You can use a recursive CTE (common table expression) figuring out the id's as you go then just do a single insert.